# Watson Conversation Pre-Processing advice

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I would like to know if there is a performance improvement in pre-processing the user input somehow. For example, removing stop-words, stemming the phrases, lemmatizing the sentences, etc...

We have been testing the service and sometimes it makes mistakes in different tenses in spanish (past tense, perfect tense, etc...) that we test in the test set and are not trained and the actual intent. The intention tested is the same that the one that is actually trained

```
I would like te get a card
I am trying to get a visa card
I am interested in mastercard
How can I get a credit card?
etc...
```

But with the training made above, it makes mistakes at the sentence "It would have been interesting to get a card".

Do you guys have any advice in the training or pre-processing task to perform better at not seen examples?

Comment: Ideally there should be no need for the text pre-processing of the examples - the idea is that the NL services as part of Watson Conversation Service will take care of everything themselves.

This doesn't mean that for particular examples and use-cases the pre-processing would not help, however we are constantly improving the service to increase the classification accuracy minimizing the need of custom pre-processing of the input.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MichalBida!. Any advise for how to train the API, is there a minimum requirement? (Not 5 as in the API documentation) for good performance? Is there a need for accents in spanish and special characters?